# what does mean javaClass in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I see usage of reflection with

```
private fun invokeMethod(parameterTypes: Array<Class<*>>?, parameters: Array<Any>?, methodName: String?): Card? {
        try {
            //val method = javaClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes)
            for (x in parameterTypes!!) println("Parameter Types: $x")
            if (parameters != null) {
                for (x in parameters) print("Parameters: $x")
            }
            val method = javaClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *parameterTypes)
            return method.invoke(this, parameters) as Card
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Class Error ${e.message}")
        }

        return null
    }
```

That is kotlin by the way,
Here is

```
val method = javaClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, *parameterTypes)
```

the method calling from

> javaClass

I know we can call the method like this

```
Test obj = new Test(); 
Class cls = obj.getClass();
cls.getDeclaredMethod("method2", int.class)
```

So my question is which class does javaClass refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [an extension property on any non-nullable type](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-class.html). Here it's applied to `this`, which can be omitted as usual. So it will return the `Class` object for the instance it's called on, equivalent to `this::class.java` (which may be the same as the class the method defined in, or its subclass).